# Got propensity score for multiple treatment groups. How can I proceed with matching?

Tags: propensity-scores, matching

I want to perform propensity score matching for multiple treatment categories. I read the popular post of [Comparing two or more treatments with inverse probablity of treatment weighting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/202698/comparing-two-or-more-treatments-with-inverse-probablity-of-treatment-weighting), and used twang, finally got propensity score for three categories.

But my question is that how can i proceed from here to match control to each treatment? I tried to do this with Matching function, which allows only binary classification and failed.